# Meaning of id() and why different objects from Process fork have the same id() value?

Tags: python

I'm trying to spawn child processes which return their results via a passed dict argument.

It appears to me that after `Process.start()` is called that the passed dict is copied in some form because change in one is not reflected in the other.  Yet, in both the parent and child process, `id()` is the same value.

From this article, I would expect that `id()` returns a unique value for an object.
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/id

> The id() function returns identity of the object. This is an integer
>   which is unique for the given object and remains constant during its
>   lifetime.

```
import json
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep

def my_format(obj):
    return ('id(obj):' + str(id(obj)) +'; obj:' + json.dumps(obj, indent = 4))

def work(result):
    result['child'] = 'only'
    sleep(5)
    # child does not see entry from parent, must be different object
    # ie missing result['parent'] == 'only'
    print('child thread: ' + my_format(result))
    return

result = {}
p = Process(target = work, args = (result,))

result['both'] = 'see'
p.start() # fork(), which copies the object including its id()
result['parent'] = 'only'
sleep(5)
p.join()
# parent does not see entry from child, must be different object
# ie missing result['child'] == 'only'
print('main thread: ' + my_format(result))
```

Unexpectedly, the child `result` and parent `result` have diverged in content.  I.e. changes in one is not reflected in the other.

```
child thread: id(obj):4385974824; obj:{
    "both": "see",
    "child": "only"
}
main thread: id(obj):4385974824; obj:{
    "both": "see",
    "parent": "only"
}
```

Comment: Where do you have different objects? There is only the `result` dictionary

Comment: The prints show they have different contents

Comment: You *modify* the object between `print` calls, but you do not *create* a new object

Comment: The `sleep` doesn't matter - you still only have **one** object, so its `id` obviously stays the same

Comment: How can I get different print results from the same object?

Comment: The object `result` is mutable. Changing the contents of a dictionary doesn't change its identity.

Comment: why do you believe the `result` object in the `work()` function is a different object from the one on the last line...?

Comment: As you quote, "The id() [...] remains constant during its lifetime." The lifetime is between creation and descruction. The *contents* of it may change during the lifetime, but the id() won't.  Think of objects like boxes; the same box may have different contents. If you put "post data" in the box, the box has different contents, it's still the same box with the same unchanged id().

Comment: @Peteris When I modify the contents in child process, the parent process does not see it.  And vice-versa.  How is this the same object?

Comment: The comments here did not look at the question carefully.  Thank you @RickTeachey for getting to the core of the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object- everything about it, INCLUDING THE ID- is copied to the process. This is not the same as `deepcopy`, which would create a new object. It is *the same object* copied to another memory space.

See this answer for more information:

[python multiprocessing arguments: deep copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983159/python-multiprocessing-arguments-deep-copy)

Comment: Thank you Rick, this must be it!

Comment: There are extra relevant resources in https://kaushikghose.wordpress.com/2016/08/26/python-global-state-multiprocessing-and-other-ways-to-hang-yourself/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055303/python-multiprocessing-global-variable-updates-not-returned-to-parent/11056415#11056415 . In essence, this seems to be an artifact of how CPython implements multiprocessing, it uses OS fork() to clone the whole python interpreter instance, it's memory space and thus also object IDs.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Peteris.  And please upvote the question (to bring it out of negative if you are reading this) as I think this is a valid confusion for developers.

Comment: @Peteris I would think, though, that producing an identical copy of the memory space would be a spec for the behavior of `multiprocessing`, no matter how the implementation actually accomplishes it. ie: having the same ids in the new memory space is probably a cross-implementation requirement.

Comment: @RazzleShazl I respectfully suggest improving the question, rather than asking for upvotes. I can see you have made some modifications with the TL;DR, but it would be better to write the question clearly. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @PeterWood I appreciate the feedback.  I have updated the question.

Comment: @RickTeachey could you clarify the answer a bit?  It almost sounds like you're saying whereas `deepcopy` would create a new object, `fork()` does not.  When in fact, they are clearly different objects in _both_ cases.

Comment: @RazzleShazl It depends on the definition of "same", I suppose. If we are in a multiverse, the RickTeachey in the universe next door would be the "same", just in a different universe. This is kind of what is going on here.